# How to get sqlalchemy to throw an error when a order_by is attempted on a Text column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need SQLAlchemy to throw an error if we try to do an order_by operation on a Text column. This is done as Oracle does not support order_by operation on Text.

I achieved doing this by:

```
@compiles(Select)
def compile_sort_on_text_for_oracle_compat(select_stmt, compiler, **kw):
    for sort_col in select_stmt._order_by_clause.clauses:
        if isinstance(sort_col, Column) and isinstance(sort_col.type, Text):
            raise AssertionError(
                '"Sort By" should not be done on a Text column as it is not supported in Oracle. '
            )
    return compiler.visit_select(select_stmt, **kw)
```

But as you can see I am using a Generic `Select` over here.
I want to know if there is a better way of doing this ? (like compiling Clause instead of Select)

Comment: Doesn't SQLAlchemy already pass back the Oracle exception ("(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: …") when it tries to run the SELECT query?

Comment: An error will be thrown only if an oracle db is used, but i want an error to be thrown for all dbs.